# Methods to bootstrap in place Backbone models on page load

Tags: backbone.js

For "Fetch", the Backbone docs say:

> Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page
>   load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped
>   in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for
>   interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents
>   with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.

Because all of my data lives in a db, the first thing I do when my app is loaded is to fetch the collections I need. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding, but how else could I have any models to show without fetching? What do the docs mean by "should already be bootstrapped in to place." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrapped data is data that would normally be fetched using XHR, but which has been instead embedded into the HTML as a serialized string in order to avoid the XHR call and thus optimize the initial page load. You still have to retrieve it from the DB on the server side in order to embed it, but sometimes overall, that results in faster page loads due to various factors such as perception, caching, etc.

In my app I used fetch anyway, but overrode `Backbone.sync()` so that `fetch()` would first check for any bootstrapped data.

```
<div class="bootstrap" data-json="...JSON data here..." data-url="/foo"></div>
```

Then a fetch for `/foo` would return the bootstrapped data, if it existed, otherwise falling back to loading over the network. It would delete that bootstrap element once it was used, so that subsequent fetches would use the network.

That way my client-side load logic could remain simple and ignorant of any loading and bootstrapping concerns.